# Подскажите, как при помощи телеграм бота создавать задачи на портале битрикс 24?

Tags: telegram-bot, битрикс, telegram, битрикс24

перерыл весь интернет, не могу найти информации, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: наверное нужно сначала изучить API Битрикс24, потом изучить API Telegram, потом написать бота, который будет с помощью API Telegram получать через мессенджер данные от пользователя и с помощью API Битрикс24 будет создавать задачи, отсылая соответствующие указанным методам запросы с имеющимися данными из телеграмма

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['b24_add_task'])
def b24_add_task(message):
    send = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите название задачи:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send, b24_add_task_1)

# намеренно пропущенный блок кода

    try:
        b24_token = requests.post(B24_oauth_token).json()['access_token']
        task = requests.post(B24_URL_TASK, json={'fields': {'TITLE': b24_task_title,
                                                            'DESCRIPTION': message.text,
                                                            'CREATED_BY': 1,
                                                            'RESPONSIBLE_ID': 1,
                                                            'TAGS': 'Telegram bot'},
                                                            'auth': b24_token})
        
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Задача №{}'.format(json.loads(task.content.decode())['result']['task']['id']))
    except Exception as b24_add_task_error:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка\n{}'.format(b24_add_task_error))
```

- [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)
- [tasks.task.add](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/tasks/task/tasks/tasks_task_add.php)
- B24_URL_TASK = https://domain.bitrix24.ru/rest/tasks.task.add.json
- B24_oauth_token - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1238373/234134